# 404 response despite resource available

Tags: http, go, redirect, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I am POSTing a `<form>` to http://0.0.0.0:3033/process and get a 307 response code.

Then I  redirect the user to a success page.

After the redirection to http://0.0.0.0:3033/success I get a 404.

But if I manually enter the url in a browser the page comes up and I get a 200 response.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main(){
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/process", processHandler).Methods("POST")
    router.HandleFunc("/success", successHandler).Methods("POST")
    router.HandleFunc("/success", successHandler).Methods("GET")
}   

func processHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(303)//<-does not work, 307 is returned
    http.Redirect(w, req, "success", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
}
```

Any idea to what is going on?

Comment: If you write header with 200 status, you can no longer redirect. The header is already written. Redirection happens with the header.

Comment: I removed the misleading 200 response.
The code above does do a redirect, but I get a 404 despite resource being available.

Comment: What are you using to register the handlers? Standard library? Some 3rd party mux (e.g., gorilla)? Have you checked the redirect request's method? Is it GET just like when you enter the url into the browser? Or is it POST, just like the original request's method? Have you registered success under POST?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307 => *"In the cases where you want the __method__ used to be __changed to GET__, use 303 See Other instead. "*; also *"The only difference between 307 and 302 is that 307 guarantees that the __method__ and the body will __not be changed__ when the redirected request is made."*

Comment: Right, use of 307 is the problem then. Or the fact that `successHandler` is registered under `GET` only and not also under `POST`. Makes sense @pigfox?

Comment: It was the succesHandler lacking a POST route.